# Why can't I output the variable sent by AJAX POST?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, razor, typescript

I am trying to post the value of the textbox and have that same value posted on the page in the "You said..." section.

My TypeScript/JavaScript is:

```
declare var document;
declare var xmlhttp;

window.onload = () => {
    start();
};

function sayHello(msg: any) {
    // Post to server.
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          // All right - data is stored in xhr.responseText
            alert("done" + " " + xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
        else {
          // Server responded with a status code.
            alert("error");
        }
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "Default.cshtml");
    xmlhttp.send("someValue=" + msg);


    return msg;
}

function start() {
    // Add event Listeners for user interaction
    var element = document.getElementById("link");

    element.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var tb = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("tbox"));

        var element = document.getElementById("response")
            .innerText = sayHello(tb.value);
    }, false);

    // Setup XMLHttpRequests (AJAX)
    if (XMLHttpRequest) {
        // Somewhat cross-browser
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        // Legacy IE
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}
```

And the HTML is (this page is *Default.cshtml*):

```
@{
    Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Home Page";

    var msg = Request["someValue"];
}
<h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>
<div id="content">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="link">Say Hello</a>:
        <br />
    <input type="text" value="dfgdfgdfg" id="tbox" />
    <br />
    <p id="response">awaiting a response.</p>
    <br />
    <p>You said:<br />
    @msg</p>
</div>
```

And I've included all references properly:
`<script src="~/App.js"></script>`

The response code I get back is 200.

Am I doing something wrong here? I've followed many tutorials, docs and so forth, and I just don't see what I'm doing wrong. It looks practically identical.

Comment: What errors/unexpected behavior are you experiencing?

Comment: what exactly is the problem, are you getting 404 or 500 when your ajax request fires?

Comment: What's actually going wrong? Do you know whether the browser is making a call? (look through firebug or chrome on networking to see if the call is being actually made)

Comment: No errors at all, @JacobT.Nielsen - it just doesn't post data. I'm trying to output the value of "tbox" after it's been posted to the server by using msg variable but nothing gets outputted. And I don't know how to check if anything is actually getting posted ajax so I'm assuming that it's just not posting. BUT... when I click the link to make it post, I get an alert that says "done."

Comment: I'm getting a 200 when the event fires, and the "done" message appears - but nothing gets outputted once it's received at the server.

Comment: Not sure about exactly what does not get outputted? Does the done alert message only output done or also the markup received?

Comment: The value of the textfield on the html page is *supposed* to be outputted, but it doesn't. And the alert message displays "done" followed by `responseText.innerText` which is the entire html of the page.

Comment: But right now you are doing nothing with the xmlhttp.responseText. You are just alerting it and then essentially throwing it away. Then the method returns your original msg!

Comment: @JacobT.Nielsen please check the HTML and the C# server-side variables and you'll understand what should be happening. Also, I just monitored Networking from IE Dev Tools and status code of ajax post is `304`.

Comment: 304 means that your result has been cached. But do you understand that when you make your ajax request what you get from xmlhttp.responseText is just text. The page that is requesting it does not do anything with it right now. Sorry but your application flow does not make much sense to me. I have tested your ajax call, C# code & and HTML/Razor. This all works fine. But you are still not doing anything with it. So I do not understand how your application should behave?

Comment: I'm sorry @JacobT.Nielsen I don't really know how to explain it any more, other than this application is just a sample app that I am using to learn how to do ajax with javascript properly. and all I am doing in this code is just posting a textbox value and trying to retrieve it serverside and then output it in to a paragraph element. The responsetext in the alert really has nothing to do with the rest of the code, I just put it there to see what was actually in a responseText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are processing an XMLHttpRequest as a POST, you need to add a couple of extra headers - add them before you call `send`, like this:

```
var params = "someValue=" + encodeURIComponent(msg);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length.toString());
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

**UPDATE - My Full Example**

Default.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    Page.Title = "Home Page";
    var msg = Request["someValue"];
}

@if (msg != null) {
    Layout = null;
    <text>You said @msg</text> 
} else {

    <h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>
    <div id="content">
        <a href="javascript:;" id="link">Say Hello</a>:
        <br />
        <input type="text" value="dfgdfgdfg" id="tbox" />
        <br />
        <p id="response">awaiting a response.</p>
    </div>
}
```

App.ts

```
declare var document;
declare var xmlhttp: XMLHttpRequest;

window.onload = () => {
    start();
};

function sayHello(msg: any) {
    // Post to server.
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          // All right - data is stored in xhr.responseText
            //alert("done" + " " + xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById("response").innerText = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
        else {
          // Server responded with a status code.
            alert("error");
        }
      }
    }

    var params = "someValue=" + encodeURIComponent(msg);
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length.toString());
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
    xmlhttp.send(params);

    return msg;
}

function start() {
    // Add event Listeners for user interaction
    var element = document.getElementById("link");

    element.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var tb = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("tbox");
        sayHello(tb.value);
    }, false);

    // Setup XMLHttpRequests (AJAX)
    if (XMLHttpRequest) {
        // Somewhat cross-browser
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        // Legacy IE
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks @Sohnee! the second line up there ("Content-type") line... It throws an `Unhandled exception at line 15, column 5 in http://localhost:1058/App.js

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: InvalidStateError` exception. Any idea what that's about?

Comment: I'm not getting that - what browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using IE 10 on Windows 8 and, on Chrome and Opera and Firefox I don't get an error but also the link doesn't work anymore

Comment: The closest I can get is IE9 on WIN7 and my example works. I'm happy to give you my whole TypeScript file.

Comment: That would be appreciated @Sohnee, I am totally hopeless with ajax. I feel like putting a hole in my desk lol.

Comment: @JamesKent I have added the view and the TypeScript file - let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try replacing:

```
xmlhttp.send("someValue" + msg);
```

with

```
xmlhttp.send("someValue=" + msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps. As stated I am a bit confused by your flow, but it might still help you.

**PageA.cshtml** (the page that houses the javascript)

```
<h1>TypeScript HTML App</h1>
<div id="content">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="link">Say Hello</a>:
    <br />
    <input type="text" value="dfgdfgdfg" id="tbox" />
    <br />
    <p id="response">awaiting a response.</p>
</div>

<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**PageB.cshtml** (the page we request via ajax call)

```
@{
    var msg = Request["someValue"];
}
<p>You said:<br />
@msg</p>
```

**App.js** (javascript file running on page A and requesting page B)

```
declare var document;
declare var xmlhttp;

window.onload = () => {
    start();
};

function sayHello(msg: any, callback) {
    // Post to server.
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                // alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            } else {
                // Server responded with a status code.
                alert("error");
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "PageB.cshtml");
    xmlhttp.send("someValue=" + msg);
}

function start() {
    // Add event Listeners for user interaction
    var element = document.getElementById("link");

    element.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var tb = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("tbox"));

        sayHello(tb.value);
        document.getElementById("response")
            .innerHTML = tb.value;
    }, false);

    // Setup XMLHttpRequests (AJAX)
    if (XMLHttpRequest) {
        // Somewhat cross-browser
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        // Legacy IE
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}
```

What I am doing is making a request from PageA to PageB. Then reading the result I manipulate the dom of PageA to contain the markup received from PageB. This markup contains the message passed along with the request.

Is this the flow you are trying to achieve?

Comment: That's pretty much it (although your code doesn't work for me. It just doesn't output the value that was sent.).

What I am trying to do is have someone enter a value in the textbox, click the link, post the textbox value and have that value re-displayed on the page after I've got it in a C# variable.

Comment: OK. I have updated the code. Now it makes the request, but does not use the response. It simply takes the original message and displays it on the page making the request.